# Navigation Drawer does not recognize custom adapter layout

Tags: android, adapter, drawer

Can someone point out what's the problem with this code snippet

`Custom adapter`

```
public class NavigationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavItem> {
private Context context;
private NavItem[] values;

public NavigationAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,NavItem[] values) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Holder holder;
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View convertView1 = convertView;
    if (convertView1 == null) {
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView1 = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent,false);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView1.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView1.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
        convertView1.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView1.getTag();
    }
    NavItem item = values[position];

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(item.icon);
    holder.textView.setText(item.name);

    return convertView1;
}

private class Holder {
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

`custom listview layout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:padding ="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rowIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rowIcon"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"/>
```

`Main activity`

```
NavItem settings = new NavItem();
settings.icon = R.drawable.ic_action_settings;
settings.name = "Settings";

NavItem send = new NavItem(R.drawable.ic_action_settings,"Sent");

NavItem[] values = new NavItem[]{
                settings,send
};

NavigationAdapter adapter = new NavigationAdapter(this, R.layout.item_row, values);
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I open the drawer it just shows a blank page. If I change the adapter to `ArrayAdapter` of string and inflate the built in layout then it works, but I want to add image next to the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced similar problem in my experience.

I solved this problem by changing :

```
public class NavigationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavItem> {

}
```

to :

```
public class NavigationAdapter extends BaseAdapter<NavItem> {

}
```

I have extended my custom adapter from BaseAdapter class which have worked for my case. Please try this if it works for you also